# Parse reduce deploy version

Tags: parse-platform

I am working on an app since few days for testing. I am using parse to store data. I have deployed cloud code lot of times since I am a beginner to parse,but now the version number has gone above 200 . Is there a way so that I can set that version number to beginning again.
I dont want to start a new app in parse again and import all the data.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the code of how you are currently setting your version number?

Comment: We do not need to set anything. When we deploy our code the parse itself increments the version number.

Comment: are you talking about the `appVersion` or `parseVersion` columns in your Installation table?

Comment: Cloudcode version..Just go to CloudCode column in Core.

Comment: That counter isn't intended to be a project's version number.  Think of it as only an FYI about the number of times you deployed.  Create your own scheme to version the app.

Comment: @danh I know that it is the number of times we deployed..But is there a way to make it zero.

Comment: No.  That's my point. Since it's the number of times you've deployed, it can be zero only when you have deployed zero times.